# Issue in converting this tradingview pinescript from v2 to v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I want to convert my script from v2 to v5 strategy and add Buy Sell Alerts. This script is working fine in v2, and I am able to see Buy/Sell Signals at screen, but also want alerts to pop up if any Buy/Sell signal appears.

Following is my script

```
//@version=2

strategy("testLearn", overlay=true, default_qty_value=1)
res = input(title=" SuperTrend", type=resolution, defval="720")
Factor=input(2, minval=1,maxval = 1)
Pd=input(10, minval=1,maxval = 1)

tp = input(5,title="Take Profit")
sl = input(2,title="Stop Loss")


Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))
MUp=security(tickerid,res,hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd)))
MDn=security(tickerid,res,hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd)))

Mclose=security(tickerid,res,close)

TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

MTrendUp=Mclose[1]>MTrendUp[1]? max(MUp,MTrendUp[1]) : MUp
MTrendDown=Mclose[1]<MTrendDown[1]? min(MDn,MTrendDown[1]) : MDn

Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown

MTrend = Mclose > MTrendDown[1] ? 1: Mclose< MTrendUp[1]? -1: nz(MTrend[1],1)
MTsl = MTrend==1? MTrendUp: MTrendDown

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green: red
plot(Tsl, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend")

Mlinecolor = MTrend == 1 ? blue : red
//plot(MTsl, color = Mlinecolor , style = line , linewidth = 4,title = "Main SuperTrend")

plotshape(cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,lime,0,0, text="==Buy==")
plotshape(cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, red,0,0, text="==Sell==")
up = Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 and MTrend == 1 
down = Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 and MTrend == -1 

alertcondition(condition=cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl, message="Buy::{{ticker}}:{{close}}")
alertcondition(condition=cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl, message="Sell::{{ticker}}:{{close}}")


num12= input(12, title='ema12')
num30= input(30, title='ema30')
num100= input(100, title='ema100')
num200= input(200, title='ema200')
ema12 = ema(close,num12)
ema30 = ema(close,num30)
ema100 = ema(close,num100)
ema200 = ema(close,num200)
plot(ema12, title='ema12', color=green, linewidth=2)
plot(ema30, title='ema30', color=red, linewidth=2)
plot(ema100, title='ema100', color=blue, linewidth=2)
plot(ema200, title='ema200', color=orange, linewidth=3)
plot(vwap(close), color=black, linewidth=3)


length = input(32, title="Length")
offset = input(0,  title="Offset")
src = input(close, title="Source")
lsma = linreg(src, length, offset)
lsma2 = linreg(lsma, length, offset)
eq= lsma-lsma2
zlsma = lsma+eq


length1 = input(20, minval=1)
src1 = input(close, title="Source")
mult1 = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = sma(src1, length1)
dev = mult1 * stdev(src1, length1)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
plot(basis, color=red)
p1 = plot(upper, color=blue)
p2 = plot(lower, color=blue)
fill(p1, p2)
```

I tried to covert this to v3 but failed. Then i tried to convert it directly to v5, I am able to fix small changes like `input` to `input.int` but getting lots of other error messages also.

Example of one error message is as follow:

```
00:41:23 — Compilation error. Line 5: The arguments 'maxval', 'minval', and 'step' cannot be used with the input() function. You can use the input.int() or input.float() functions to specify a range of input data values
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to v3 first then use the converter tool to convert it to v4 and then v5.

To convert this to v3, you can consult with the [migration guide](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html).

Your main issue will be lines like below:

```
TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
```

As the migration guide tells you, *self referenced variables* are not allowed anymore. So you should fix such statements like below:

```
TrendUp = 0.0
TrendUp := close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
```

Comment: This was really helpful, you pointed out the exact issue that I was struggling with. Thanks. Can you also help me in modifying it to get alerts with buy/sell indicators.